# Creating an array with two sets of values?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a feeling that I have been overthinking this, but I have been having trouble with creating a proper array that has one value associated with another.

The list I'm working with:

Solution 1: 2.5 pH, Solution 2: 5.5 pH, Solution 3: 10 pH, Solution 4: 7.2 pH, Solution 5: 9 pH

I am trying to show the pH's that are acidic (<7) with the corresponding solution number.

I created an array:
`import numpy as np`

`data_list_numpy = np.array(['2.5','5.5','10','7.2','9'])`

Then did this to show pH's below 7:
`smaller_than_7 = np.empty([0])`

`for item in data_list_float:`

`if item <7:`

`smaller_than_7 = np.append(smaller_than_7,item)`

`print('Acidic solutions are',smaller_than_7)`

How can I create an array for the pH of each solution and use a loop that goes through each element of the array? I want to list the pH's with the corresponding solution number.

Comment: "a proper array that has one value associated with another". You mean, a `dict`?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
smaller_than_7 = data_list_numpy[data_list_numpy < 7]
```

If you want concatenate with int [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)

```
smaller_than_7 = np.r_[0, data_list_numpy[data_list_numpy < 7]]
```